# Ampscript %%[IF]%% statement woes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to check if a personalization attribute is empty before I output it, but I cannot get the Ampscript to work.

Here's my code:

```
%%[IF Length("Provider Rating") > 0) THEN]%% 
<tr><td width=100>Rating:</td>
<td width=400>%%Provider Rating%%</td></tr>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Is this because my attribute has a space in it?  If so, what should I do?  Here is the error:

```
Errors found in the email HTML Body.
Category : AMP Script
Functions and Custom Objects:("

Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 <br>Invalid Content: <br>IF Length("Provider Rating") > 0) THEN]%% Rating: %%Provider Rating%% %%[

Errors found in the email Text Body.
Category : AMP Script
Functions and Custom Objects:("

Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 <br>Invalid Content: <br>IF Length("Provider Rating") > 0) THEN]%% Rating: %%Provider Rating%% %%[
```

Thanks!
Neil

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kelly!  It still seems to not work, however.

Answer (score 3):

Try it as this:

```
%%[IF Length([Provider Rating]) > 0 THEN]%% 
    <tr><td width=100>Rating:</td>
    <td width=400>%%Provider Rating%%</td></tr>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Passing it in with the quotes makes it a string. Use the brackets for spaced attribute names.

Hindsight - make your attributes *without* spaces.

**Updated**
The above code snippet is working for me as well. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  It still doesn't work however.  Here is the error: 
Errors found in the email HTML Body.
Category : AMP Script
Functions and Custom Objects:("
Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 <br>Invalid Content: <br>IF Length([Provider Rating]) > 0) THEN]%% Rating: %%Provider Rating%% %%[

Comment: Is provider rating a number field,  or a text field?

Comment: It is a text field.  I also tried using another text field without spaces, but it still didnt work: 
Errors found in the email HTML Body.
Category : AMP Script
Functions and Custom Objects:("
Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: 0) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 <br>Invalid Content: <br>IF Length(Employer) > 0) THEN]%% Rating: %%Provider Rating%% %%[

Comment: I made a quick update that should help a bit.  I would also make this numeric and not text. The greater than operator shouldn't work on text fields.

Comment: Hmm - i am trying to check if the text field is empty. Any other suggestions?  I tried %%[IF !Empty(Employer) THEN]%% but still got the error:

Comment: Errors found in the email HTML Body.
Category : AMP Script
Functions and Custom Objects:("
Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: !Empty(Employer) MemberID: 1002582 JobID: 0 The function call uses an unrecognized function name. Function Name: !Empty Function Call: !Empty(Employer) <br>Invalid Content: <br>IF !Empty(Employer) THEN]%% Rating: %%Provider Rating%% %%[

Comment: Ok - you should be ok with the Length().  I think what's missing is in the second portion. Try removing `%%Provider Rating%%` and see if that works. I so, make it %%[Provider Rating]%%

Comment: Thanks Kelly!  Seems when I used %%[Provider Rating]%% there were no errors, but the personalization string was not inserted.  I changed it back to %%Provider Rating%% and somehow it started working.  Thanks again for engaging me in this back & forth!

Comment: I'll throw this in an account and see if I can update with something as well.

Comment: Hi Neil, use %%[IF NOT EMPTY(Employer) THEN]%%

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra parenthesis in there. And you need brackets around any personalization string containing spaces.  This should work:

```
%%[ IF Length([Provider Rating]) > 0 THEN ]%% 
  <tr><td width="100">Rating:</td>
  <td width="400">%%Provider Rating%%</td></tr>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

[Here's](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/) the syntax guide.

Comment: `%%[Provider Rating]%%` does not work.  When it's a personalization string, it fails with the brackets. And yes - the extra parens will cause a problem.  I should have copied straight from my test account. Thanks!